# Get the selected element's HTML Tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know you can do this, but every time I Google it I get how to select all elements of a certain tag.

So, e.g.:

```
alert($('#my-wrapper').someJSMethod());
{...}
<div id="my-wrapper"></div>
```

Would alert "DIV" actually. I'm selecting elements with jQuery by the way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
alert($('#my-wrapper').get(0).nodeName);
//or:
alert($('#my-wrapper')[0].nodeName);
```

Or, no need for jQuery:

```
alert(document.getElementById('my-wrapper').nodeName);
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out non-jquery method; it's overkill for a simple thing like this. IMHO, people depend on it way too often.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#my-wrapper')[0].tagName
```

Comment: `nodeName` is better way to do it.

Comment: showing my age then I guess, not much benefit and tagName saves k ;)

Comment: Some additional reference (bottom/notes): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.nodeName

Comment: For me `tagName` is preferable, if it's definitely a tag name you want. It's marginally more readable and if you make a mistake it's slightly more obvious in that you get `undefined` instead of a fairly-arbitrary string for other nodeTypes. (It's not as obvious as it should be, though, since `undefined` is a horrible wrongness. A reasonable language would have raised an exception.) I completely disagree with the linked site that `#text` is somehow preferable to `undefined`, and feel that on IE, `nodeName`'s failure case on Document is worse than `tagName`'s unexpected existence on `Comment`.

Comment: If you're definitely dealing with an element (which we are in this case) then it makes no functional difference at all whether you use `nodeName` or `tagName`. Beyond that, it's a matter of personal taste. I tend to use `nodeName`, for no particular reason.